# preg_replace words longer than x characters

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need a preg_match pattern which got all strings longer than x characters. I need this for the following reason: The user uploads a pdf which is stored on my server. then the script reads the pdf and extracts cleartext (I need this for search functionality the database). This works not in all cases proper. Sometimes there are long patterns in this string. for example things like that:

```
PDF document properties Control PDF opening mode Can be configured to add 
functionality to Acrobat Distiller Free: Creates PDFs without annoying watermarks Free: Fully functional, not a trial and d
oes not expire Over 5 million satisfied customers Over 1000 Enterprise Customers worldwide  Please visit us at www.pdf995.com to learn more.
 This document illustrates several features of the Pdf995 Suite of Products. APPROVEDShortlyaftertheGenevaBOFsession,the
www-vrmlmailinglistwascreatedtodiscussthedevelopmentofaspecificationforthefirstvers
ionofVRML.Theresponsetothelistinvitationwasoverwhelming:withinaweek,therewereov
erathousandmembers.Afteraninitialsettling-
```

For this reason I need to cut all strings longer than x (for example 30) characters, because this strings make no sense to store in the database.

My code line is this, but I appreciate help for the pattern (first var):

```
$result = preg_replace('\S{30,}', '', $result);
```

I took this because \S is for any non-whitespace character and {30,} for all stings longer than 30 characters.

Is this correct or is there a better way? It works, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right way.

Kind regards

IW

Comment: what if some of that cut text is actually relevant?

Comment: For your stated goal with preg_replace, you have a decent solution, but I might first split on non-word characters. Are you just storing the text in the DB without further processing?

Comment: I store pdf files on my server and the files are indexed in the db. I need the text only for one reason: user can search with words and the backend is searching for words to find the matching pdf files. So the long words over 30 characters are not relevant. I suppose these long words are code, not words and no user would search with such long words anyway.

Alderin, how does this work with first splint on non-word characters?